# Change colors for the Pantheon terminal emulator

Tags: colors, elementary-os, pantheon

I am using Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 12.04) and I would like to change the coloring scheme for Pantheon Terminal window. Here's what I've tried:

1. Elementary Tweaks
2. Dconf Editor
3. shell commands

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings background '#090911111a1a' 
   $ gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings foreground '#d9d9e6e6f2f2' 
   $ gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings palette '#000000000000:#acac6d6d7474:#7474acac6d6d:#acaca4a46d6d:#6d6d7474acac:#a4a46d6d‌​acac:#6d6dacaca4a4:#e6e6e6e6e6e6:#262626262626:#d6d6b8b8bcbc:#bcbcd6d6b8b8:#d6d6d‌​3d3b8b8:#b8b8bcbcd6d6:#d3d3b8b8d6d6:#b8b8d6d6d3d3:#ffffffffffff'
   ```

None of those things worked. This is what I would like to use: https://github.com/Mayccoll/Elementary-OS-Terminal-Colors

Comment: Those three things that you tried aren't very specific. What shell commands, what did you do in the editor, what tweaks did you attempt?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at ZSH and Oh-My-Zsh, probably has everything you could want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navigate to your home directory. Show hidden files.
2. Open `.bashrc` in a text-editor.
3. Change `#force_color_prompt=yes` to `force_color_prompt=yes` (I.e. uncomment the line number 43). If such a line doesn't exist, add it.
4. Now you can change the color scheme using `sh theme-file.sh`, `dconf editor` or by running the individual commands for foreground, background and palette colors.

[Source](https://plus.google.com/102525769390642006147/posts/dv6PUYYtYoe)

Answer (score 0):

The dconf editor has worked for me, but I also saw this solution and it worked easily.

https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/blob/master/content/themes.md

They have several different color themes listed along with a command string to copy and paste into terminal. Then it just works.

Here's an example:
https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/blob/master/content/themes.md

You don't even need to use sudo to change the theme.

Comment: that link is broken, new link here: https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/tree/master/themes